# How to get memory type in Java?

Tags: java, memory

I want to get the memory type (Manufacturer, Chip (e.g. DDR2-400)...) using a Java method. I'm searching for something like the one for the CPU:

```
public String getCPU(){
   String cpu;
   cpu = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");

   return cpu;
}
```

The return value is "Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel" I want for the same thing for memory. What's the method to do this?

Comment: It is completely OS dependent. Your method may, or may not work, for any other OS/JRE combination...

Comment: Why are you using Java to get detailed OS information? You propably will need to write `native` libraries, meaning for each OS you will have a different implementation.

Comment: Yes, I know that but it works for my use.

Comment: If you just call `getenv()` without any arguments you'll get a `Map` showing all the environment keys and values.

Comment: It's a support tool. If you open a ticket your OS information are also part of the ticket.

Comment: Do you know the O/S you are running on?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 64 Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this information on Windows OS you could get the information with `wmic` and parse the output.

get all informations

```
wmiv MemoryChip
```

get only specific informations

```
wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel,Capacity,DeviceLocator,Manufacturer,PartNumber,SerialNumber
```

**output** (real data anonymised)

```
BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator   Manufacturer   PartNumber        SerialNumber  Speed
BANK 0     4000000000  ChannelA-DIMM0  SuperRAM       RAM1111111111111  12345678      1600 
BANK 2     8000000000  ChannelB-DIMM0  DuperRAM       RAM2222222222222  98765432      1600
```